# Setting up Global variables in Google Cloud Platform (GKE) for cluster workload config yaml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, config, google-kubernetes-engine, cluster-computing

Is there a way to configure global variables and use in cluster workload, because we are using NFS and whenever we switch to new NFS, the ip has to be changed in 100s of workloads which is now hard to do manually. So we are looking for global variables kind of config, so we can change in one place but it reflects in all the cluster workloads. We are unable to find global variables kind of option in GCP. Will somebody suggest how can we achieve this.

Thanks a lot guys for your help.

Comment: Were you looking for this https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/configmap ?

Comment: Do you mean the environment variables that are displayed by `printenv` command in Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean variables available inside container (pod) then the answer is yes - you can set them up and change afterwards in a single place for all pods.

As [dany L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9253778/dany-l) pointed out - [ConfigMaps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/configmap) are the way to do this.

When creating a new deployment clisk on **+ ADD ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE** button and add your key & value (in your case your NFS storage path):

[image]

After deployment is ready you can edit the path in [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/configmap) page of your GCP console. Now you find your ConfigMap (it's name starts with the name of the deployment); click on it's name and go to the `YAML` tab:

[image]

There you can change your configuration any way you like. Add or remove keys etc. When you're done click on `SAVE` button.

For the changes to take effect you need to restart/recreate your pods; first configure your `kubectl` to connect to your cluster:

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster-name --zone my-zone-name --project my-project-name`

Next you find out your deployment name: `kubectl get deployments`, you should get something similar:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ (wb)$ kubectl get deployments
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-1   3/3     3            3           5h8m
```

So - in my case the deployment name is `nginx-1`. To restart all the pods we're using a workaround (since `kubectl` doesn't have a restart feature): `kubectl rollout restart deployment nginx-1`.

Now your pods will be deleted and new ones created in their place and the variable has been updated.

To see that that the pods are really updated run `kubectl get pods`:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ (wb)$ kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-1-5ff4b9d9c6-8hdhs   1/1     Running       0          6s
nginx-1-5ff4b9d9c6-fp2wh   1/1     Running       0          8s
nginx-1-5ff4b9d9c6-gq2v4   1/1     Running       0          4s
nginx-1-785bf9956f-9t4kc   0/1     Terminating   0          9m18s
```

As you can see Kubernetes already started new pods and is terminating the last of the old ones.

To check if the variable was updated just run this on one of the pods:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ (wb)$ kubectl exec pod-name -- printenv | grep key_name
```

In my case value was changed as intended and I got:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ (wb)$ kubectl exec your-pod-name -- printenv | grep storagepath
storagelocation:yourpath
```